# Custom Plugin Develoment, Form Action

Tags: php, plugin-development, forms

I'm trying to get into the custom Wordpress Plugin development, I'm putting together a demo plugin at the moment.

I have some basic knowledge of PHP.

I created an HTML form `form.php` and I want to pass the data of this into `sendmail.php`

How would I go about this?

In my form I have `<form method="POST" action="sendmail.php">`

But each time the form is submitted the page tries to redirect and Wordpress gives me the "Page Not Found" error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending form data via PHPMailer - How to action PHP script from a form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100043/sending-form-data-via-phpmailer-how-to-action-php-script-from-a-form)

Comment: You need to define all the actions in your functions and the functions should become your actions hooks good place to start with developers.wordpress.org/plugin